# A Puzzling Playlist

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story, music

My friend loves puzzles, and one day I walked into her room while she was listening to music. I asked what she was listening to, and she listed off the albums in her playlist:

> Accustomed to Nothing - Accustomed to Nothing
> After Everything Now This - The Church
> Doggumentary - Snoop Dogg
> Eph Reissue - Fridge
> Radio-Activity - Kraftwerk
> Scarlet's Walk - Tori Amos
> Scripted - Icon For Hire
> Trench - twenty one pilots

I asked if it ever got repetitive, but apparently she listens to it on shuffle. She likes listening to the playlist while solving a certain type of puzzle, saying it was "an essential component" to her success, and that I should be able to figure out what type of puzzle it was curated for.

What type of puzzles is this eclectic playlist for?

Comment: How much knowledge of the songs is required? Titles, artists, lyrics, music videos, etc.?

Comment: I can't really say much without giving the puzzle away, but I can safely say you don't need to watch any of the music videos or listen to any of the songs (although I would personally recommend Trench!)

Comment: @bobble Also just to clarify, this list is of albums, not songs. Regarding my last comment, I'm not sure if the [[enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle)] tag would be appropriate - again, can't really explain further without ruining the puzzle :/

Comment: If "what do I do to start" is an essential part of the puzzle, then [[tag:enigmatic-puzzle]] applies. Sorry about mixing up songs and albums; I know almost nothing about music.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This playlist serves as inspiration to your friend when she attempts to solve:

> **Cryptic clues**

Why? Firstly, note that:

> Each of these albums contains a track named after **a Periodic Table element**:
>
>  [Accustomed to Nothing](https://www.discogs.com/Accustomed-To-Nothing-Accustomed-To-Nothing/release/2271718) = Einsteinium (Es)
>  [After Everything Now This](https://www.discogs.com/The-Church-After-Everything-Now-This/master/39338) = Chromium (Cr)
>  [Doggumentary](https://www.discogs.com/Snoop-Dogg-Doggumentary/master/354465) = Platinum (Pt)
>  [Eph Reissue](https://www.discogs.com/Fridge-EPH-Reissue/release/66032) = Yttrium (Y)
>  [Radio-Activity](https://www.discogs.com/Kraftwerk-Radio-Activity/release/218454) = Uranium (U)
>  [Scarlet's Walk](https://www.discogs.com/Tori-Amos-Scarlets-Walk/master/82487) = Carbon (C)
>  [Scripted](https://www.discogs.com/Icon-For-Hire-Scripted/release/3024802) = Iodine (I)
>  [Trench](https://www.discogs.com/Twenty-One-Pilots-Trench/master/1432821) = Chlorine (Cl)

Finally:

> Take the symbols that usually represent these elements and rearrange ('*shuffle*') them thus to spell out the answer:
>
>  **Cr-Y-Pt-I-C-Cl-U-Es**!

PS Note a small hint concealed in the text:

> An "essential component" - a synonym for 'component' is '**element**'!